# How do I catch when my backgroundworker thread is aborted?

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

Will the `.disposed` event handler pick it up? I can't seem to figure out how to assign this event handler- this is how I am assigning the other event handlers:

```
            bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(
            delegate(object o, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
            {
                lb_status.Text = args.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
                this.Refresh();
            });
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            delegate(object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
            {
                lb_status.Text = "Ready";
                BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
                source.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
                source.ResetBindings(false);
                button1.Enabled = true;
            });
```

I'm aborting the thread during a try/catch using `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()`.

Comment: `Thread.Abort` is evil - doubly so in your case as you're doing it on a thread borrowed from the thread pool.

Comment: can you elaborate? and/or recommend a better approach?

Comment: @LeeTickett: I removed my answer because it's incorrect. You should totally stop using `Thread.Abort` though. If you want to abort, just `return` from inside your handler.

Comment: @jon, i'm quite deep (like a function call within a function call within a function call within my handler... that's why i thought aborting would be my best way out

Comment: `Thread.Abort` leaves the `AppDomain` in an unknown state, so it should only be used when destroying the `AppDomain.` Use cooperative cancellation instead - i.e. signal to the thread that you want it to stop and allow it to do so.

Comment: @LeeTickett: Eh... throw any other type of exception, catch it at the top level of your handler and then `return`?

Comment: can you elaborate? i can't currently see how i can bale out of all the parent functions without rewriting everyone to return and check some form of error code?

Comment: Can't you create a backgroundworker, and then do something like namebackgroundworker.Join(); ?

Comment: Why can't use use `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync`?  Then check the `Cancelled` flag in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event?

Comment: how would I call that from inside a function called by the bw?